# How to print particular id(i.e word ) from the result

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi i have the following code:

```
Z = [ [<Entity:0*7fasdas55c:type1101(1101,NGRID)id:-2600>, <Entity:0*5fafaef45c:type1101(1101,NGRID)id:-3665>] 
, [<Entity:0*7fasdas55c:type1101(1101,NGRID)id:-5600>, <Entity:0*5fafaef45c:type1101(1101,NGRID)id:-545465>] ]

 edge1= ansa.basecollectentity(constant.nastran, Z[0],'NODE')
 print(edge1)
```

and my result is

```
[<Entity:0*7fasdas55c:type1101(1101,NGRID)id:-2600>, <Entity:0*5fafaef45c:type1101(1101,NGRID)id:-3665>]
```

Enen though code is written in ansa python, my question is General

I would like to write a code such that it goes through the 'edge1' and prints the number after ids with two different names: like

Node1= 2600

Node2= 3665

Pls help me with writing the code, thanks in advance

Comment: What is ansa python?

Comment: Presumably, `Entity` is a class, and `id` is one of its attributes. What does `print(edge1[0].id)` print?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You must first show whatever you already tried, or we can guide you, but in no circumstances we should write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each class controls its own printable representation with the [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)  special method.

The number you're looking at, `id:` could potentially be anywhere in the Entity, in any field, or somewhere in an internal datastructure, or nowhere and calculated at display time. It might easily be an `id` property as @PM2Ring's comment suggests - but it might not be.

So it's either a very specific question - you need to examine the Entity for an appropriate field or method to get the ID. And you haven't said what it is, so that could be anything.

Or it's a general question about processing the `repr()` value - which is probably not what you want to do ever, really.

But if you did want to, it would be:

```
for count, item in enumerate(edge1):
    id = repr(item).split(':')[-1].rstrip('>')
    print "Node" + str(count), id
```

Answer (score 1):

in ansa say you have a entity eg:

```
nod=<Entity:0*7fasdas55c:type1101(1101,NGRID)id:-2600>
```

to print id you can use:

```
Print(nod._id)
```

result:

```
2600
```

you can also use `._type` to get the type of entity you are dealing with

hope it helps